# MinWidth take no effect

Tags: c#, wpf, statusbar, textblock, css

I have a StatusBar with two TextBlock-items:

```xml
    <StatusBar 
        x:Name="MainStatusBar"
        Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="30"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
        <StatusBarItem HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <TextBlock
                x:Name="StatusBarTextBlock"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                Text="{Binding StatusBarText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </StatusBarItem>
        <StatusBarItem HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <TextBlock 
                x:Name="StatusBarTimeBlock"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                MinWidth="75"
                Text="{Binding SearchTime, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </StatusBarItem>
    </StatusBar>
```

When `StatusBarTextBlock` is to long, `StatusBarTimeBlock` will be lesser then `75px`.

Have you any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your first `StatusBarItem` takes whole place and second `StatusBarItem` doesn't fit in `StatusBar`

Try this code an look what it does

```xml
<StatusBar
    x:Name="MainStatusBar" Margin="14,462,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="600" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <StatusBarItem MaxWidth="550">
            <TextBlock
            x:Name="StatusBarTextBlock"
            TextWrapping="NoWrap"
            Text="{Binding StatusBarText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </StatusBarItem>
        <StatusBarItem HorizontalAlignment="Right" MinWidth="75">
            <TextBlock 
            x:Name="StatusBarTimeBlock"
            TextWrapping="NoWrap"
            Text="{Binding SearchTime, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </StatusBarItem>
</StatusBar>
```

You have 600px `StatusBar` and Max of 550px first StatusBarItem... So there is only 50px left for second `StatusBarItem` so it doesn't fit in your StatusBar. In your code you didn't specity `Width` property for your `StatusBarTextBlock` so it takes all(if text is long enough).

Now let's try something different...

```xml
<StatusBar
    x:Name="MainStatusBar" Margin="14,462,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="600" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <StatusBarItem HorizontalAlignment="Right" MinWidth="250">
            <TextBlock 
            x:Name="StatusBarTimeBlock"
            TextWrapping="NoWrap"
            Text="{Binding SearchTime, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </StatusBarItem>
        <StatusBarItem>
            <TextBlock
            x:Name="StatusBarTextBlock"
            TextWrapping="NoWrap"
            Text="{Binding StatusBarText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </StatusBarItem>
</StatusBar>
```

I switched order of `StatusBarItems` and set MinWidth of `TimeBlock StatusBarItem` to 250px... Well it's added to the `StatusBar` and it no longer ignores MinWidth beause it's first item and it fits into 600px `StatusBar`.

So `MinWidth` is ignored only if there is not enough space left in `StatusBar`.

But if you paid attention to the code I provided You probably noticed something. There is

```xml
<StatusBarItem HorizontalAlignment="Right" ... >
```

And that's not saying that your `StatusBarItem` with `StatusBarTimeBlock` will be at right... because Items in `StatusBar` are always added from left to right no matter what. 
So it may be aligned to right, but it's only aligned to next item or end of `StatusBar` if there is no other item.

**EDIT**

My answer was composed to answer your question

**When StatusBarTextBlock is too long, StatusBarTimeBlock will be less than 75px.
Have you any ideas why?**

And it did, but as it seems it's not what you wanted.

As I said items in `StatusBar` are always added from left to right no matter what. And That's because it's items are hosted in `DockPanel`. 
If you know how `DockPanel` works you also know, that you can Dock some items to the right.

So you can do this. It happens to be what you want but didn't ask for.

```xml
<StatusBar x:Name="MainStatusBar" Margin="14,490,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="600" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <StatusBarItem DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" MinWidth="75">
            <TextBlock 
            x:Name="StatusBarTimeBlock"
            TextWrapping="NoWrap"
            Text="{Binding SearchTime, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </StatusBarItem>
        <StatusBarItem>
            <TextBlock
            x:Name="StatusBarTextBlock"
            TextWrapping="NoWrap"
            Text="{Binding StatusBarText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </StatusBarItem>
</StatusBar>
```

Notice that `StatusBarTimeBlock` is "first in XAML" again, but it's docked to right.

Comment: If TimeBlock is the fist Item in XAML it´s also the first Item in drawn Window.

Comment: The MinWidth in StatusBarItem HorizontalAlignment="Right" MinWidth="75" is also not betterment :-(

But i think about something, like "overlow"-Property for the StatusBarTextBlock. (such as "hidden" in html: http://de.selfhtml.org/css/eigenschaften/anzeige/overflow.htm)

Comment: @user2063921 yes thats what I said. I was just trying to explain how it works and why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @user2063921 Please read my answer again, I made an edit. To provide code you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are right!

```
    <StatusBar 
        x:Name="MainStatusBar"
        Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="30"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">

        <StatusBarItem HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                       DockPanel.Dock="Right">
            <TextBlock 
                x:Name="StatusBarTimeBlock"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                MinWidth="75"
                Text="{Binding SearchTime, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </StatusBarItem>

        <StatusBarItem HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <TextBlock
                x:Name="StatusBarTextBlock"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                Text="{Binding StatusBarText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </StatusBarItem>

    </StatusBar>
```

If StatusBarTimeBlock is the first Block and StatusBarItem has DockPanel.Dock="Right", so my MinWidth stays allways by 75 px!

Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome :) Please don't add the answer when it's not necessary.   You will make it easier for future readers :)If my answer helps you please use comments. And feel free to upvote if it's worth it. Glad I helped :)